# VSTS Build definition for Xamarin Android always fails with error " A supported task execution handler was not found. T..."

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-pipelines-build-task

VSTS Build definition for Xamarin Android always fails with error " A supported task execution handler was not found. This error usually means the task does not carry an implementation that is compatible with your current operating system. Contact the task author for more details."

We are using on-premise agent and the version is 2.117.1

Demands are as shown in the build definition

1. AndroidSDK
2. JDK
3. MSBuild
4. Xamarin.Android
5. msbuild

Comment: What's the operating system of your build agent? What're tasks of build definition? Which step it throws exception? Can you share the build log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true > queue build> then share the log)

Comment: It is Mac. I have looked up in the internet and it looks like the tasks uses Powershell script. And it is not compatible with mac. Is there a mac version of those build tasks?

Comment: I have managed to us the msbuild engine directly from command line and it works now in mac.

Comment: No mac version for powershell build task, similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419098/run-powershell-build-step-in-vsts-agent-installed-on-mac. On the other hand, you said it works now in mac, you can post an answer and accept it as answer.

Comment: Added my answer. If you feel that is correct then please upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is struggling to do the same thing. You can make use of the MSBuild command line utility provided by Microsoft to directly build it from the command line. On Mac it is called xbuild and in windows it is msbuild. But recently I have seen warning messages in the build logs that xbuild will be deprecated soon use msbuild instead. So I have used MSBuild command to build a xamarin.android project. 
Command is given below for reference

```
msbuild /t:Clean;Build;PackageForAndroid /p:Configuration=$(BuildConfiguration) /p:AndroidKeyStore=true /p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=$(alias) /p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=$(KeyStorePassword) /p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=<Keystore> /p:AndroidSigningStorePass=$(KeyStorePassword) <CSProj file path>
```

I am still checking the keystore side of this command. If get more info then will add it here.