# VSTS Run Powershell Script on Mac with Parameters

Tags: powershell, xamarin.ios, azure-devops, visual-studio-mac

I have a Xamarin.Forms project wherein the Android project is built in VSTS using a hosted build agent which runs a powershell script at run-time.

I need to run the same powershell script against the Xamarin.iOS which uses an On Premise Mac Build Agent. But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42428479/1190885) and a comment under the answer also had the same question regarding parameters, so I am posting the solution here since the issue is slightly different and that question has an accepted answer.

First off, I installed powershell on the mac using [these instructions](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/installation/linux.md#macos-1012) and I modified the shell script task to include the Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) environmental variables that I wanted to pass to the powershell script.

[image]

Next, I pass the arguments through to the called powershell script by slightly modifying the shell script mentioned by the [referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42428479/1190885).

```
#!/bin/bash
powershell ./Version.ps1 $1 $2
```

Finally, in the powershell script, I catch the arguments that have been passed through using using param like this:

```
param([string]$version, [string]$path)
```

Wherein I can now use the variables $version and $path which contain the original arguments entered in VSTS to the needs of my powershell script.

Comment: The restriction stopped me from doing so the day of and the day after, then I forgot about it :P